DVD Cover Containing a Girl and a Desolate City
So quite a few years ago I was in possession of a DVD that I believe was to do with zombies or something that wiped out most of the human race and sadly I lost the DVD before I had a chance to watch it and I can't remember the name of the movie or any other details except for the front cover - and even that might be a bit hazy.
The front cover was of this young girl holding onto a teddy bear and behind her was what you could consider to be a standard American suburban street but it was desolate and quiet, and I think the sky might have been red.
Beyond that I guess for an estimated year of release it would be anywhere between 2000 and 2009.
I know this isn't a lot to go on but if anyone has any ideas it would be much appreciated.

Similar art in Zombie 108, but it's from 2012 (it's always possible it ripped off your movie's cover).

A better match than the one I made above would be the zombie film Wicked Little Things (AKA Zombies) with Chloe Grace Moretz from 2006. Here's the cover art:

But if you want to see a girl with a teddy bear actually fighting zombies, there's always Nuiguruma Z. ;)
